# DB2 using With clause inside insert

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to insert into multiple tables, but the same subselect should be used in the insert stataments. When I am using With Clause, it does not work

This is working

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1, COL2)
SELECT COL_1, COL_2 
FROM TABLE_A
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

This subselect should be used in other insert statements too..

```
  SELECT COL_1, COL_2 
  FROM TABLE_A
  JOIN ...
  WHERE ...
```

Try to solve it so but does not work, for the first insert

```
WITH TEMP AS (
SELECT COL_1, COL_2 
      FROM TABLE_A
      JOIN ...
      WHERE ...);

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1, COL2)
    SELECT COL_1, COL_2 
    FROM TEMP
```

How can I do this to use the same subselect for whole my insert statements?

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1, COL2) WITH ... SELECT ...`

Comment: A common table expression only has meaning within the context of a statement of which it is a part; you cannot reference it from another statement.

Comment: Ok just understand but when I want to use it in a stored procedure, can I realize this by using temporary table or cursor for the subselect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may obviously use some temporary table to store the same result set, bu you may insert into multiple tables with the same statement as well.

```
CREATE TABLE A AS (SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES) DEFINITION ONLY;
CREATE TABLE B AS (SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES) DEFINITION ONLY;

WITH 
  T AS (SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES)
, IA AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM NEW TABLE 
  (
    INSERT INTO A (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME)
    SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
    FROM T
    WHERE TABSCHEMA LIKE 'SYS%'
  )
)
, IB AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM NEW TABLE 
  (
    INSERT INTO B (TABSCHEMA, TABNAME)
    SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
    FROM T
    WHERE TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
  )
)
-- You may use whatever SELECT statement here instead like:
-- SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
-- You can't use "select into nowhere" in SP, so you need something
-- like below with some V_DUMMY variable declared
-- SELECT 1 INTO V_DUMMY FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT (1) CNT FROM IA) AS A_CNT
, (SELECT COUNT (1) CNT FROM IB) AS B_CNT
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

| A_CNT | B_CNT |
| --- | --- |
| 432 | 41 |

```
SELECT COUNT (1) AS A_CNT FROM A
```

| A_CNT |
| --- |
| 432 |

```
SELECT COUNT (1) AS B_CNT FROM B
```

| B_CNT |
| --- |
| 41 |

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/8vIzUwFf)

Comment: I do not understand the need for `SELECT *  FROM NEW TABLE`. You not define NEW TABLE anywhere

Comment: This is a way to select affected rows from data change statements like INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE. Refer to the description of [data-change-table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clause-table-reference#sdx-synid_data-change-table-reference) of `subselect`.

Comment: Ok just understand...
Is it a way to do it without the select at the end
`WITH TEMP
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM TEST
), IB AS 
(
  SELECT *
  FROM NEW TABLE 
  (
    INSERT INTO TEST (COL_1, COL_2)
SELECT 60, COL2
FROM TEMP
  )
)
SELECT *
FROM TEMP;`

I do not need the select here.

Comment: Yes, you have to SELECT finally, since it **must be** a SELECT statement to achieve what you need - changing multiple tables with a single statement. But you don't have to use whatever of tables participated, if you don't need some statistics on changed rows. If the goal is just to INSERT, then you may use, say, `SELECT 1 FROM NEW TABLE    (INSERT ...) LIMIT 1` and `SELECT 1 INTO V_DUMMY FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` to not make Db2 do some unnecessary internal processing.

Comment: Ok I am litte confused due to the error below, I simplified my code, but still get same error
**[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "INTO" was found following ".TEST
)
SELECT 1
".  Expected tokens may include:  "IN".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11**  Here is my code `DECLARE V_DUMMY INT DEFAULT 0;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'WITH TEMP
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM TEST
)
SELECT 1
INTO ''' || V_DUMMY || ''' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1';
END

Comment: There is different technique for dynamic sql. Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/NH9-k7MT) link. BTW, don't use `LIMIT 1` as I erroneously suggested above. Use `SELECT COUNT (1) FROM NEW TABLE (INSERT ...)` count instead.

Comment: Hmm its working fine, but when I have more than two insert blocks for different tables than I got an error like
**{0:0} The data type for parameter or SQL variable "'WITH TEMP AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM" is not supported in the  routine, compound SQL statement, or parameter list of a cursor value constructor.. SQLCODE=-789, SQLSTATE=429BB, DRIVER=4.28.11**

Comment: Ask new question with some fully reproducible example. It's hard to guess about your unknown code.

Answer (score 0):

Should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COL_1, COL2)
WITH TEMP AS ( SELECT COL_1, COL_2
                 FROM TABLE_A
                 JOIN ...
                 WHERE ... )
SELECT COL_1, COL_2
 FROM TEMP;
```